# Is it possible to build this type of program in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to build a QA program that will crawl all the pages of a site (all files under a specified domain name), and it will return all external links on the site that doesn't open in a new window (does not have the target="_blank" attribute in the href).

I can make a php or javascript to open external links in new windows or to report all problem links that don't open in new windows of a single page (the same page the script is in) but what I want is for the QA tool to go and search all pages of a website and report back to me what it finds.

This "spidering" is what I have no idea how to do, and am not sure if it's even possible to do with a language like PHP. If it's possible how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use any function like fopen/fread or even file_get_contents to read the HTML of a given URL to a string, and then you can use DOMDocument::loadHTML to parse it, and DOMXPath to get a list of all <a> elements and their attributes (target, href).

Answer (score 1):

yes its very much possible to do it using php.

try using `curl` to get the page and `regex`, more specifically `preg_match_all` function to filter the links

More on curl here: [PHP: cURL - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
More on regex here: [PHP: preg_match_all - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

regex's are likely to fail / turn up false positives.  Use PHP's DomDocument class and/or xpath to find links on a given page.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Answer (score 0):

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5439-PHP-Crawl-a-site-and-retrieve-the-the-URL-of-all-links.html
Provides a class to crawl / spider a site and retrieve the the URL of all links. You can  modify the script to check, if the page is valid using curl or file_get_content (as mentioned above).